# How to read the value of roles and store it in a variable

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell

I wanted to read the value of "roles" from the below json file (demo.json).

```json
"A": {
  "User": "xyz",
  "Role": {
    "Role1": [
      "piolet"
    ],
    "Role2": [
      "driver"
    ],
    "Role3": [
      "technician"
    ]
  },
  "Id": "1",
}
```

I am using grep to read role ,but this command gives me only

```
{
```

My expected result is:

```json
"Role1": [
  "piolet"
],
"Role2": [
  "driver"
],
"Role3": [
  "technician"
]
```

Please provide me some solution to do this ,please prefer some basic utility if possible.

Comment: check out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449061/18877734)

Comment: That's not valid json. When it is, use `jq`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep with -A n option to print N lines after matching lines.
Like this.

> grep "Role" -A 2 demo.json

Comment: I will use this command only if there are fixed rows. But i my case "Role" may have any number of rows .